# open pdf file with extjs4 in firefox or chrome

Tags: extjs4

I work with extjs 4

I want to open a pdf file

I have a file named test.pdf which is under C:

I installed PDF plugin in my browser (firefox 23.0.1)

I try with this code :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/MyProject/extjs/resources/css/ext-all-neptune-rtl.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/MyProject/extjs/ext-all-rtl.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/MyProject/theme/lib/pdf/compatibility.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/MyProject/theme/lib/pdf/pdf.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">




Ext.onReady(function() {

    Ext.widget('panel', {
        title: 'My PDF',
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        items: {
            xtype: 'component',
            autoEl: {
                tag: 'iframe',
                style: 'height: 100%; width: 100%; border: none',
                src: 'C:\test.pdf'
            }
        },
        renderTo: 'output'
    });

});
</script>
```

But when I run my application I didn't show my pdf file

I download pdf.js and compatibility.js from  :

https://github.com/SunboX/ext_ux_pdf_panel/tree/master/lib/pdf.js

Answer (score 0):

Your PDF needs to be in your Webserver's root directory or where ever your static content is getting served from.